# Perl SQLite DBI SELECT with bind not working

Tags: perl, sqlite, select, bind, dbi

Why does the second SELECT statement in this sample code return an empty result?

```
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db', '', '', { AutoCommit =>1, PrintError => 1, RaiseError => 1 }) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $r = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('select 123 where 5 > 2', { Slice => {} }) or die $dbh->errstr;

print Dumper $r;

$r = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('select 123 where 5 > ?', { Slice => {} }, 2) or die $dbh->errstr;

print Dumper $r;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            '123' => 123
          }
        ];
$VAR1 = [];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite-1.40/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm#Functions_And_Bind_Parameters) documentation it says this:

> This is because DBD::SQLite assumes that all the bind values are text (and should be quoted) by default.

One way around it is this:

```
$r = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('select 123 where 5 > (?+0)', { Slice => {} }, 2)
    or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Another probably better way is to set the sqlite_see_if_its_a_number database handle attribute before querying, or even when connecting.

```
$dbh->{sqlite_see_if_its_a_number}=1;
```

Comment: If I were you I'd actually use the first example ikegami provided. sqlite_see_if_its_a_number has some horrible consequences that could catch you out. For example, try inserting '1.2340' into a char column with sqlite_see_if_its_a_number and you'll lose the trailing 0.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
$r = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('select 123 where 5 > 0+?', { Slice => {} }, 2);
```

Alternatively, do:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select 123 where 5 > ?');
$sth->bind_param(1, 2, DBI::SQL_INTEGER);
$sth->execute;
$r = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
```